# D3 Nested append with update, selection issues

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3 selections bake my noodle!

I have a series of nested selections that need to be updated based on input fields. I have 3 out of the 4 working. The main issues is with the 3rd selection update *innerSArray*, the yellow bars are not updating. I think the issues is coming from further up the chain, but not sure. I had to `.merge()` previous selects.

To update a nested `.append()`, I've done a new `d3.selectAll()`, but am not sure this is the correct way of doing this. I've done this for *innerM* and *innerSM*.

How can I get the 3rd select updating properly? Should I be breaking the nested appends apart?

```css
.outer {
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: grey;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
    }
    .inner {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      background-color: cyan;
      height: 50px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .innerM {
      display: flex;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      background-color: magenta;
      height: 25px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .sr {
      display: flex;
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 12px;
    }
    .sm {
      display: flex;
      background-color: black;
      height: 6px;
    }
```

```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>#</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <p>Inner: <input id="increment" type="number" value="1" step="1" max="5" /></p>
    <p>InnerM: <input id="incrementM" type="number" value="1" step="1" max="5" /></p>
    <p>SR: <input id="incrementSR" type="number" value="1" step="1" max="5" /></p>
    <p>SM: <input id="incrementSM" type="number" value="1" step="1" max="5" /></p>
    <div id="anchor"></div>
    <script>
      const increment = document.getElementById('increment');
      const incrementM = document.getElementById('incrementM');
      const incrementSR = document.getElementById('incrementSR');
      const incrementSM = document.getElementById('incrementSM');
      const anchor = d3.select('#anchor');
      const data =  [
       {
         "outer": [
           {
             "inner": [
               { "r": 40,
                 "m": 10,
                 "s": []
               },
               { "r": 70,
                 "m": 13,
                 "s": []
               },
               { "r": 10,
                 "m": 15,
                 "s": [
                   {
                     "r": 20,
                     "m": 5
                   }
                 ] },
               { "r": 15,
                 "m": 9,
                 "s": []
               },
               { "r": 52,
                 "m": 20,
                 "s": []
               },
               { "r": 96,
                 "m": 30,
                 "s": [
                   {
                     "r": 50,
                     "m": 10
                   }
                 ] },
               { "r": 192,
                 "m": 60,
                 "s": []
               },
               { "r": 301,
                 "m": 50,
                 "s": []
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
     ];
      
      increment.addEventListener('change', function() {
        update(data);
      });
      
      incrementM.addEventListener('change', function() {
        update(data);
      });
      
      incrementSR.addEventListener('change', function() {
        update(data);
      });
      
      incrementSM.addEventListener('change', function() {
        update(data);
      });
      
      
      function update(data) {

        // main data
        let root = anchor.selectAll('.root').data(data);
        root.exit().remove();
        root = root.enter()
              .append('div')
                .attr('class', 'root')
              .merge(root)
        
        // outer array
        let outer = root.selectAll('.outer').data(function(d) { return d.outer });
        outer.exit().remove();
        outer = outer.enter()
                .append('div')
                  .attr('class','outer')
                .merge(outer);

        // inner array
        let inner = outer.selectAll('.inner').data(function(d) { return d.inner; });

        // UPDATE INNER
        inner
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .style('width', function(d) { return d.r*increment.value+'px'; });

        inner.exit().remove();

        inner = inner.enter()
            .append('div')
              .attr("class", "inner")
              .style('width', function(d) { return d.r+'px'; })
            .append('div')
              .attr("class", "innerM")
              .style('width', function(d) { return d.m+'px'; })
            //.merge(inner); I think there might be an issue here, removing it helps, but not a complete fix
        
        // UPDATE INNER-M - Not sure if this is the best way to update
        let innerM = d3.selectAll('.innerM')
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .style('width', function(d) { return d.m*incrementM.value+'px'; });
        
        
        // Child array
        let innerSArray = inner.selectAll('.innerM').data(function(d) { return d.s; })
        
        innerSArray // This doen't get updated
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .style('width', function(d) { console.log(d.r); return d.r*incrementSR.value+'px'; });
            
        innerSArray.exit().remove()
        
        innerSArray = innerSArray.enter()
          .append('div')
            .attr('class','sr')
            .style('width', function(d) { return d.r+'px'; })
          .append('div')
            .attr('class','sm')
            .style('width', function(d) { return d.m+'px'; })
          .merge(innerSArray);
          
        // UPDATE INNER-SM - Not sure if this is the best way to update
        let innerSM = d3.selectAll('.sm')
          .transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .style('width', function(d) { return d.m*incrementSM.value+'px'; });
        
      }
      
      //run once
      update(data);
  
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Do you mean to make innerSArray select all `'.innerM'` and not select `'.sr'`?

Comment: `innerSArray` controls `.sr` via input `incrementSR` and needs to increase size independent of the other controls including `innerM` which controls  `.innerM` via input `incrementM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by splitting the double append on the `.inner` selection to it's own nested selection. This required wrapping `.innerM`'s returned data in an array literal. I was then able to continue nesting selections. I had previously tried it this way, before posting this question, but had another issue with the structure of the data. The `s` array wasn't being declared in every object. i.e. missing the `s` property entirely instead of being an empty array. This caused issues with the data join.

```css
.outer {
   border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: grey;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
  }
  .inner {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   background-color: cyan;
   height: 50px;
   position: relative;
  }
  .innerM {
   display: flex;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   background-color: magenta;
   height: 25px;
   position: relative;
  }
  .sr {
   display: flex;
   background-color: yellow;
   height: 12px;
  }
  .sm {
   display: flex;
   background-color: black;
   height: 6px;
  }
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>#</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <p>Inner: <input id="increment" type="number" value="1" step="1" max="5" /></p>
  <p>InnerM: <input id="incrementM" type="number" value="1" step="1" max="5" /></p>
  <p>SR: <input id="incrementSR" type="number" value="1" step="1" max="5" /></p>
  <p>SM: <input id="incrementSM" type="number" value="1" step="1" max="5" /></p>
  <div id="anchor"></div>
  <script>
   const anchor = d3.select('#anchor');
   
   const increment = document.getElementById('increment');
   const incrementM = document.getElementById('incrementM');
   const incrementSR = document.getElementById('incrementSR');
   const incrementSM = document.getElementById('incrementSM');
   
   const data =  [
     {
      "outer": [
       {
        "inner": [
         { "r": 40,
          "m": 10,
          "s": []
         },
         { "r": 70,
          "m": 13,
          "s": []
         },
         { "r": 10,
          "m": 15,
          "s": [
           {
            "r": 20,
            "m": 5
           }
          ] },
         { "r": 15,
          "m": 9,
          "s": []
         },
         { "r": 52,
          "m": 20,
          "s": []
         },
         { "r": 96,
          "m": 30,
          "s": [
           {
            "r": 50,
            "m": 10
           }
          ] },
         { "r": 192,
          "m": 60,
          "s": []
         },
         { "r": 301,
          "m": 50,
          "s": []
         }
        ]
       }
      ]
     }
    ];
   
   increment.addEventListener('change', function() {
    update(data);
   });
   
   incrementM.addEventListener('change', function() {
    update(data);
   });
   
   incrementSR.addEventListener('change', function() {
    update(data);
   });
   
   incrementSM.addEventListener('change', function() {
    update(data);
   });
   
   
   function update(data) {

    // main data
    let root = anchor.selectAll('.root').data(data);
    root.exit().remove();
    root = root.enter()
       .append('div')
       .attr('class', 'root')
      .merge(root)
    
    // outer array
    let outer = root.selectAll('.outer').data(function(d) { return d.outer });
    outer.exit().remove();
    outer = outer.enter()
         .append('div')
         .attr('class','outer')
        .merge(outer);


    let inner = outer.selectAll('.inner').data(function(d) { return d.inner; });

    inner
     .transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .style('background-color','green')
     .style('width', function(d) { return d.r*increment.value+'px'; });

    inner.exit().remove();

    inner = inner.enter()
      .append('div')
      .attr("class", "inner")
      .style('width', function(d) { return d.r+'px'; })
     .merge(inner);


    let innerM = inner.selectAll('.innerM').data(function(d) { return [d]; });
    
    innerM
     .transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .style('width', function(d) { return d.m*incrementM.value+'px'; });
    
    innerM.exit().remove();
    
    innerM = innerM.enter()
      .append('div')
      .attr("class", "innerM")
      .style('width', function(d) { return d.m+'px'; })
     .merge(innerM)


    let sr = innerM.selectAll('.sr').data(function(d) { return d.s; });
    
    sr
     .transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .style('width', function(d) { return d.r*incrementSR.value+'px'; });
    
    sr.exit().remove();
    
    sr = sr.enter()
      .append('div')
      .attr("class", "sr")
      .style('width', function(d) { return d.r+'px'; })
     .merge(sr)


    let sm = sr.selectAll('.sm').data(function(d) { return [d]; });
    
    sm
     .transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .style('width', function(d) { return d.m*incrementSM.value+'px'; });
    
    sm.exit().remove();
    
    sm = sm.enter()
     .append('div')
     .attr("class", "sm")
     .style('width', function(d) { return d.m+'px'; })

   }
   
   //run once
   update(data);
 
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```